# Does the term "upper extremity" include hands?

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology

I see on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_limb that the term "upper extremity" seem to include hands. However, in many hospitals, there is a "Hand & Upper Extremity Service", which would tend to indicate that the term "upper extremity" does not include hands.

Does the term "upper extremity" include hands?

Comment: Generally, *upper extremities* refers to arms (and everything attached to them), while *lower extremities* are the legs.

Comment: I suspect that "hand" is separated out because it is often a surgical subspeciality. Hands are complicated.

Comment: Interestingly, while hands include fingers with a lot of innervation, almost all muscles for hand are located in arm. 2OP: please accept answer if it is satisfactory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, and the same is written on [Farlex Free Dictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/upper+extremity), the *upper extremity* or *superior limb* includes:

- the shoulder girdle
- the arm
- the forearm
- the hand

Again, on this [Dartmouth Medical School](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~humananatomy/part_2/chapter_6.html) page, the upper limb bones are described and the article includes the bones of the hand.

So, **anatomically speaking**, the upper limb includes the hand.